# Как отправить запрос на создание сертификата (csr) на УЦ Microsoft по URL на Android

Tags: java, android, сертификат

Мне нужно отправить запрос на создание сертификата удостоверяющему центру по URL `http://www..../certsrv` и получить в ответ сертификат.

Как это можно сделать и можно ли вообще?

Код по созданию *csr* работает, ошибок не выдает. А как его теперь отправить?

```
KeyPair myKeyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair();
X500Principal subject = new X500Principal("CN=Test V3 Certificate");

PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = new PKCS10CertificationRequest
                   ( "SHA1withRSA",
                      subject,
                      myKeyPair.getPublic(),
                      null,
                      myKeyPair.getPrivate()
                    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут есть какой-то пример кода:
http://mobilitydojo.net/2013/04/30/programmatically-enrolling-for-certificates-from-certsrv/
Как послать запрос на сертификат и получить его по HTTP.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы прямо в точку попали, у меня как раз CA Microsoft, весь интернет излазила и ничего не нашла для android. Сейчас буду разбираться.